# How do I echo a table with the combined results of two similar queries from two different databases?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have two different (yet almost identical) databases and I and trying to produce a table which will display the combined results of a query on the two databases. 
(In MySql workbench, these databases are completely separate, and contain the databases that are being queried, I'm not sure if that makes a difference but it may be useful to know).

I need the results table to show the following:

number | company | db1 count | db2 count |

Number and Company are in both databases, the only difference between the two is that the count in one is different.

**Eventually there will be a fifth column, which will show the difference between the two counts, but I will get to that eventually.

I've looked at many different ideas with regards to getting the result I want, but I still have no idea really.
Where the number in db1 and db2 are the same, I need to display the count for each.
The code I have at the moment is:

```
// Creating the connection
$conn1 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db1);
$conn2 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db2);

// Test connection
if ($conn1->connect_error) {
    die ("Connection failed: " . $conn1->connect_error);
} 
elseif ($conn2->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn2->connect_error);
}

$sql1 = "SELECT num.number AS Number, com.name As company, count(*)   As db1 count 
                    FROM db1.db.job_processing AS jp
                    LEFT JOIN db1.db.number AS num ON num.id=jp.number_id 
                    LEFT JOIN db1.db.company AS com on com.id=num.company_id 
                    WHERE jp.show=1 AND jp.processing_complete=1 
                    AND jp.call_start_time BETWEEN '2016-12-17' AND '2017-01-03'
                    GROUP BY Number
                    ORDER BY Number
                    LIMIT 20";
$result1 = $conn1->query($sql1);

$sql2 = "SELECT num.number AS Number, com.name AS company, COUNT(*) AS db2 Count
                FROM db2.db.job_processing AS jp
                LEFT JOIN db2.db.number AS num ON num.id=jp.number_id 
                LEFT JOIN db2.db.company AS com on com.id=num.company_id 
                WHERE jp.show=1 AND jp.processing_complete=1 
                AND jp.call_start_time BETWEEN '2016-12-17' AND '2017-01-03'
                GROUP BY Number
                LIMIT 20";
$result2 = $conn2->query($sql2);


if ($result1 = $conn1->query($sql1) && ($results2 = $conn2->query($sql1))) {
        echo"<TABLE><caption>Total Call Count Overview</caption><TR>
        <TH>Number</TH>
        <TH>Company</TH>
        <TH>db1 Count</TH>
        <TH>db2 Count</TH></TR>";

        //This is where I think my problems are arising
        while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc() && ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc())) {
            echo"<TR><TD>". $row1["number"]. "</TD>";
            echo"<TD>". $row1["company"]. "</TD>";
            echo"<TD>". $row1["db1 Count"]. "</TD>";
            echo"<TD>". $row2["db2 Count"]. "</TD></TR>";
        }
            echo"</TABLE>";
    } else {
        echo"O Results";
        }   

    $conn1->close();
    $conn2->close();
```

I think it's the end part where I am stuck. I have also looked at the following solution:

```
if ($result1 = $conn1->query($sql1)) {
    echo"<TABLE><caption>Total Call Count Overview</caption><TR>
    <TH>Number</TH>
    <TH>Company</TH>
    <TH>db1 Count</TH>
    <TH>db2 Count</TH></TR>";

    while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo"<TR><TD>". $row1["number"]. "</TD>";
        echo"<TD>". $row1["company"]. "</TD>";
        echo"<TD>". $row1["db1 Count"]. "</TD>";
        echo"<TD>". $row2["db2 Count"]. "</TD></TR>";
    }
        echo"</TABLE>";
} else {
    echo"O Results";
    }

if ($result2 = $conn2->query($sql2)) {
    echo"<TABLE><caption>Total Call Count Overview</caption><TR>
    <TH>Number</TH>
    <TH>Company</TH>
    <TH>db1 Count</TH>
    <TH>db2 Count</TH></TR>";

    while ($row_devel = $result_devel->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo"<TR><TD>". $row1["number"]. "</TD>";
        echo"<TD>". $row1["company"]. "</TD>";
        echo"<TD>". $row1["db1 Count"]. "</TD>";
        echo"<TD>". $row2["db2 Count"]. "</TD></TR>";
    }
        echo"</TABLE>";
} else {
    echo"O Results";
    }
```

Those are just two of the solutions I've been trying.
I just don't get how I can merge the two queries together, and I realise I have probably gone completely wrong in a number of places, but any assistance I could get would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**
With regards to the databases, on is a 'write to' db, and the other is a 'report' db. So, every time a call is made to a number it should be added to the table. My query should be counting the number of times a number appears. I just want to display if there are any differences between what is reported (the report db) and what is actual (the write to db).

Comment: Can I just be clear. Are they two separate databases or two separate tables?

Comment: one thing I can tell u for sure u have an error here : `if ($result1 = $conn1->query($sql1)) && ($results2 = $conn2->query($sql1)) {`  You closed your condition here :`if ($result1 = $conn1->query($sql1))`

Comment: Activiting Error Reporting is important

Comment: You also have an Error here : `while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) && ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {`

Comment: You closed your while here : `while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc())`

Comment: The line should be : `while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc() && ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc())) {`

Comment: @PhpDude Does it make sense to say they are two separate databases, db1 and db2, that contain a database of the same name, db, in them. Does this make them separate database servers? Sorry, I'm quite new to this.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I see your point there, I've changed that now but it has had no effect unfortunately. I'll edit the question to reflect that, thank you.

Comment: @seb I am jus curious so i can be sure to provide you with an answer or at least some insight. So you have two totally seperate databases with their own tables right?

Comment: @PhpDude I appreciate your help.Okay, so one is a Reportdb, and one is Writedb. Inside of them, (when I work with Mysql Workbench), they both contain a database called SBdb. SBdb is the database that I am doing the queries on. They also contain other various databases too. Does this make sense??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit :**

Assuming your results are like this :

Write

```
number company    db1 Count
1      SuperCorp  5
2      SuperCorp  10
```

Report

```
number company    db2 Count
2      SuperCorp  10
3      SuperCorp  20
```

If you want to display a table like this

```
number company    db1 Count db2 Count
1      SuperCorp  5         0
2      SuperCorp  10        10
3      SuperCorp  0         20
```

You need to merge the results of the two queries before to print them to screen. This is possible thanks to your 'number' column which can be used as the key of your PHP array.

You also need to modify your SQL queries to include a fake column representing the other database count :

```
$sql1 = "SELECT num.number AS Number, com.name As company, count(*)   As \"db1 count\", 0   As \"db2 count\" 
                FROM db1.db.job_processing AS jp
                LEFT JOIN db1.db.number AS num ON num.id=jp.number_id 
                LEFT JOIN db1.db.company AS com on com.id=num.company_id 
                WHERE jp.show=1 AND jp.processing_complete=1 
                AND jp.call_start_time BETWEEN '2016-12-17' AND '2017-01-03'
                GROUP BY Number
                ORDER BY Number
                LIMIT 20";

$sql2 = "SELECT num.number AS Number, com.name AS company, COUNT(*) AS \"db2 Count\", 0   As \"db1 count\" 
            FROM db2.db.job_processing AS jp
            LEFT JOIN db2.db.number AS num ON num.id=jp.number_id 
            LEFT JOIN db2.db.company AS com on com.id=num.company_id 
            WHERE jp.show=1 AND jp.processing_complete=1 
            AND jp.call_start_time BETWEEN '2016-12-17' AND '2017-01-03'
            GROUP BY Number
            LIMIT 20";
```

And then combine the 2 results before to display them, like this :

```
$results = array();
while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
     //Adding all the 1st query results 
     $results[$row['number']] = $row;
}

while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
     if(! isset($results[$row['number']]) {
          //Mean's this row is not present in the 1st database, so add it
          $results[$row['number']] = $row;
     }else {
          //Just merging the db2 Count from the 2nd database since other fields are the same
          $results[$row['number']]['db2 Count'] = $row['db2 Count'];
     }         
}


if ($results) {
      echo"<TABLE><caption>Total Call Count Overview</caption><TR>
      <TH>Number</TH>
      <TH>Company</TH>
      <TH>db1 Count</TH>
      <TH>db2 Count</TH></TR>";

    foreach($results as $row) {
         echo"<TR><TD>". $row["number"]. "</TD>";
         echo"<TD>". $row["company"]. "</TD>";
         echo"<TD>". $row["db1 Count"]. "</TD>";
         echo"<TD>". $row["db2 Count"]. "</TD></TR>";
    }
    echo"</TABLE>";
} else {
     echo"0 Results";
}
```

Comment: nice try but hardly usable. how would you know that the order of rows is exactly the same?

Comment: Do the order of rows is important ?

Comment: That's two **different** databases. A row can be deleted i one.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I updated the question to explain the databases

Comment: @GuillaumeSTLR Would you please mind just explaining your answer briefly please? As I said, I'm quite new to this and it would help me in understanding what I should be doing. thanks

Comment: @seb I hope the last edit will be clear enough for you

Comment: @GuillaumeSTLR It does, thanks very much! It makes a lot of sense. However, I'm still having trouble though, the webpage isn't displaying anything when I run this, just a blank page. Would there be something to do with the connection that may be wrong?

Comment: can you add the lines :
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

On the top of your php script and tell me the output ?

Comment: @GuillaumeSTLR the error I get is: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean... I assume this is something to for with my first query??

Comment: OK, i just edited the queries in my example. The fact is you had a type in your SQL query. Aliases with spaces must be quoted by ". I.e the query SELECT column AS My alias FROM table must be changed by SELECT column AS "My alias" FROM table

Comment: @GuillaumeSTLR So it seems the issue was lying with where I had dbb1.db.number, db1.db.company, etc... I took out db1 and db2 before these and it has ran okay, and outputted something at least. Am I correct in thinking that without the correct db being pointed to, both queries will call from the same database?

Comment: Your thinking is quite good but not in this case!  When you create your database connection with the mysqli() function, your 4th parameter is the database name. So every queries made with this connection are performed to this database by default. So you don't need to re-specify the database name in your queries.
I hope you understand what I mean, my english is bad sorry !